# How do I call a PHP file via jQuery on click function

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this button called `save` button. On clicking on it, I want it to call a PHP file on the server which will then let user download a text file with some data.

This is my button code

```
<img id="save" class="normal_button"  src="buttons/save.png">
```

This is my jQuery file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#save").click(function(){
        jQuery.get("download.php"); 
    });
```

Here is my php file named download.php

```
<?php
    echo "connected";
?>
```

Comment: The jQuery documentation works wonders with this kind of quesions: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Is the file static or you need to dynamically retrieve and download the file?

Comment: Separately, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [*How do I ask a good question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: `$.get("downlaod.php", function (data) {
    alert(data);
}).fail(function () {
    alert("error");
});
` try this. If error alert is coming, that means something is wrong with either `download.php` or the way it is called, may be the path is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("download.php", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: refrence: -  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp
good luck!